# Jquery Font Size Manipulation TextArea Cutout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text area that I want to change the font size of the text using a + and a - button.

I know how to get the font size to change using javascript/jquery. That all works great. However my problem is that as the font size grows it begins to stretch out of the text box. The top half of the first row will be tucked under the top bar of the text input area. I tried adjusting the line height proportionally to the increase in font size but it doesn't seem to solve the problem

here is my code:

HTML

```
<div style="color: #0D1E28">
       <a href="#" id="minustext">-</a>
       <a href ="#" id="resetfont">
       <span style="font-size: 9px; letter-spacing: -3px;">A</span>
       <span style="font-size: 16px;">A</span>
       </a>
       <a href="#" id="plustext">+</a>
   </div>
<textarea name="txtOutput" id="txtOutput" style="width: 600px; height: 550px; line-height: 8.5; overflow: auto; font-size: 21.5px;" rows="2" cols="20" readOnly="readonly">
</textarea>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#plustext").click( function () { resizeText(1); });
            $("#minustext").click( function () { resizeText(-1); });
            $("#resetfont").click(function () { $("#txtOutput").css('font-size', "14px"); });
        });

        function resizeText(multiplier) {

            if ($("#txtOutput").css('font-size') == "") {
                $("#txtOutput").css('font-size', "12px");

            var currentFontSize = $("#txtOutput").css('font-size');
            var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
            var newFontSize = (currentFontSizeNum + (multiplier * 0.5)) + "px"; ;

            var currentLineHeight = $("#txtOutput").css('line-height');

            if (currentLineHeight == "normal") {
                currentLineHeight = "1";
            }

            var currentLineHeightNum = parseFloat(currentLineHeight, 10);
            var newLineHeight = (currentLineHeightNum + (multiplier * 0.5));

            $("#txtOutput").css('line-height', newLineHeight).css('font-size', newFontSize);
        }
```

suggestions?

Comment: This code doesn't work. You set font size line this: $("#txtRegistryReportOuput").css('font-size','12px') not this: $("#txtRegistryReportOuput").css('font-size') = "12px";

Comment: sorry I will update it. I tried to change the names for public purposes but I missed some. Thanks for catching that

Comment: @George - The problem was not (only) with the id, it is that you are trying to assign a value to the result of a function call, which you cannot do.  The proper way to accomplish what you are trying to do is to set the font-size as the second parameter in your call to `.css()`.  Ie, `.css("font-size", "12px")`, not `.css("font-size") = 12px`.

Comment: Oh great. Thanks for the feedback. That is a bug I had not noticed and in this case would probably never have surfaced as I had set the default font size within the style attr of the textarea. However the only good bug is a patched one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some mods to your code to get it to work on my end, I think it's cleaner and more efficient as well (see below). I haven't done a lot of testing but it seems to work in IE8 & FF.

IMO the line-height should adjust itself provided the line-height property is set to 'normal'.  And I found that was exactly the case in Firefox. However, I did experience the problem you referenced in IE. In order to overcome it I had to replace the textarea with a clone of itself.  Apparently, this forces IE to recalculate the proper line height.  Hope this helps.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#plustext").click(function (e) { resizeText(1); e.preventDefault(); });
    $("#minustext").click(function (e) { resizeText(-1);  e.preventDefault();});
    $("#resetfont").click(function (e) { $("#txtRegistryReportOuput").css('font-size', "14px");  e.preventDefault();});
});

function resizeText(multiplier) {
    var textarea = $("#txtoutput"); 
    var fs = (parseFloat(textarea.css('font-size')) + multiplier).toString() + 'px';    // Increment fontsize
    var text = textarea.val();                                                          // Firefox won't clone val() content (wierd..)
    textarea.css({'font-size':fs}).replaceWith( textarea.clone().val(text) );           // Replace textarea w/ clone of itself to overcome line-height bug in IE
}
</script>


<div style="color: #0D1E28">
   <a href="#" id="minustext">-</a>
   <a href ="#" id="resetfont">
       <span style="font-size: 9px; letter-spacing: -3px;">A</span>
       <span style="font-size: 16px;">A</span>
   </a>
   <a href="#" id="plustext">+</a>
</div>
<textarea name="txtOutput" id="txtoutput" style="width: 600px; height: 550px; line-height: 8.5; overflow: auto; font-size: 21.5px;" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Comment: I took some pieces of your code however you changed the multiplier function of what I had originally posted to increase the font size by one instead of a half which wasn't a huge deal but just seemed odd. Was there a specific reason? also, as more of a "spiker" than a "polisher" could you explain what made your changes more efficient?

Comment: I should have mentioned that. IE8 did not like increasing the font size by a half px so I moved it to a full px. As for performance, I wrote that because the new code wasn't performing any line height calculations. However, I forgot that I had to perform the textarea clone/replace in order to overcome the IE line height bug.  That probably slows down my code considerably.

Answer (score 1):

This is one weird bug.  By removing the node from the dom and re-inserting it, that seems to solve the problem.

```
$("#txtOutput").remove().appendTo("body");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jyFfw/

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I ended up going with Joe's just because his answer accounted for an odd firefox quirk as well but otherwise this would have been perfect.